# R - Value contained in set

Tags: r, search

This is likely a repeat question but I did some searching and maybe couldn't find the right keywords to search by...

Is there a function which tests if a variable value is contained in a particular set of values?

For example, assume I had this magically function 'contains', I would like it to have the following property:

`contains(value = 5, set = c(2:6))` would return `TRUE`, where

`contains(value = 5, set = c(2,3,4,6,7))` would return `FALSE`.

Obviously, I could create this function, but I'm hoping a package or option exists.

Comment: Have you looked at `%in%` ?

Comment: Apparently not, thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

There are several very simple ways to do this. The `%in%`-Operator is propably the most intuitive.

```
> 5 %in% 2:6
[1] TRUE
```

See `?match`for some more information.